# What is good about writing Java code in XML format as in Spring configuration?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

As a .Net developer who started Java dev for less than a year, one thing that puzzles me is the wide usage of Spring configuration file. Let me clarify:

In the case of an IoC container, I haven't seen the community being interested in setting up their Catalog/Module/Etc. through xml config in any other platform than Java.

The XML configuration is usually used as a highly verbose alternative to calling constructors/factory methods. This clearly is a disadvantage over code as is not type-safe, too verbose, and not indexable in IDEs (e.g. Find Usages of a Method)

Other IoC frameworks such as Autofac support xml configuration but in those non-java platforms XML config is unpopular.

My Question:

**Is there a best/practice design principle, etc backing this choice of XML configs for IoC or its merely a historical habit?**

Comment: I believe the reason is historical.  And Apache Ant also uses XML, and came along about the same time, so I think the Java world just "got used to XML" or bought into the XML buzz.  For the record I hate the XML configuration too.

Comment: I'm with you brother. Down with String based programming!

Comment: Apart from the reasons cited, another benefit is that data is generally safer than code, because it is more amenable to static analysis. (I do hate the way the SO thought-police censor any discussion on whys and wherefores).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML and Properties files do not need to be re-compiled, allowing you to make in-deployment changes on a server environment.

For example, you can have 2 bean implementations and swap which one is injected:

```
<bean id="impl1" ... />
<bean id="impl2" ... />

<bean id="dependent" ... >
    <constructor-arg ref="impl1"/>
</bean>
```

You can add or remove items to `Collection` type items:

```
<util:set id="some_set">
    <value>value #1</value>
</util:set>
```

Also for controlling environments for unit testing, if you have a set of XML files, one of which is for DB connections, then that's the one XML file you replace for your unit tests which need an in-memory DB, and can't connect to the real macoy at dev time:

```
src/main/resources/
    - META-INF/spring/
        service-context.xml
        dao-context.xml
        datasource-context.xml

src/test/resources/
    - META-INF/spring/
        datasource-context.xml   // this is the test version of that context
```

Comment: I understand the role of properties files and xml as Configuration parameters which can be changed across domains. However, IoC configurations such as calling constructors, factory methods, etc are tightly coupled with the code and method/constructor signatures.
An example is web.Config for IIS applications which is based on xml but is purely for configuration purpose not coding.

Comment: Based upon you comment, I have expanded my answer with examples.

Comment: Above can done through modules and NamedParameters when setting up IoC container. Such that the test package gets different modules or there are devo, and prod modules. 
https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules

Comment: Fine. You asked for reasons - I gave them. I'm not really interested in discussing why .NET is better than Java.

Comment: I don't have a bias for .Net same is for Guice, that supports modules. My comment is mainly concerning, is that the real reason?

Comment: It's my reason. That and I find XML much easier to work with than annotations for wiring together dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

When we are talking about Spring you are not limited to XML configuration. Since version 3 of the Spring framework, you can configure everything using Java Annotations. However, you are limited. If you want to change something, you have to recompile your application.

You can find useful hints about how to design concise configuration using XML.
http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/07/30/enterprise-spring-framework-best-practices-part-3-xml-config/

Comment: i dont think this answers the question. he isnt asking if there's an alternative, i think he's asking why everyone uses XML (specially if there's an alternative)

Answer (score 2):

I found it somewhere,

> 1.Configuration is centralized, it’s not scattered among all different components so you can have a nice overview of beans and their wirings
>   in a single place.
>
> 2.If you need to split your files, no problem, Spring let you do that. It then reassembles them at runtime through internal  tags or
>   external context files aggregation.
>
> 3.Only XML configuration allows for explicit wiring – as opposed to autowiring. Sometimes, the latter is a bit too magical for my own
>   taste. Its apparent simplicity hides real complexity: not only do we
>   need to switch between by-type and by-name autowiring, but more
>   importantly, the strategy for choosing the relevant bean among all
>   eligible ones escapes but the more seasoned Spring developers.
>   Profiles seem to make this easier, but is relatively new and is known
>   to few.
>
> 4.Last but not least, XML is completely orthogonal to the Java file: there’s no coupling between the 2 so that the class can be used in
>   more than one context with different configurations.

[For more details refer this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/consider-replacing-spring-xml)

Answer (score 1):

The XML allows you to alter your configuration without recompiling your program, sacrificing type safety for flexibility.

Some Java organizations also see an added advantage in letting non programmers such as field technicians or customers to modify the configuration setup.

Another possible advantage is creating user oriented custom customization tools (Pun?) which can allow GUI creation/modification of the XML files based on user choices.

Personally I don't like the world of XML based programming. It is too prone to run time errors, and difficult to debug using standard debuggers.

Comment: Wow - it's hard enough for a programmer to edit Spring XML config files, I sure wouldn't trust that to a field tech.  However, for simpler config files yes, that's a plus.